# Timing the shortcircuit in Python gives unexpected results

Tags: python, time, short-circuiting

```
import time as dt 

success = True
can_test = True 


time = 0

for i in range(10000000):
  start = dt.time()
  if success and can_test:
    stop = dt.time()
    time+= stop-start


print(f'"and" operation took: {time} seconds')


time = 0

for i in range(10000000):
  start = dt.time()
  if success or can_test:
    stop = dt.time()
    time += stop-start


print(f'"or" operation took: {time} seconds')
```

When I run the above python program, I expect the and operation to be slower than the or operation (because I learned short-circuiting will reduce the time of execution). However, not only does the result turn out exact opposite but is also fluctuating. I can understand the fluctuation! (because of background processes). But why are the results turn out opposite! what is happening?

Here is a sample result.

```
"and" operation took: 5.200342893600464 seconds
"or" operation took: 5.3243467807769775 seconds
```

Comment: Pythons `timeit` module is more suitable for these type of tests. E.g. try with `min(timeit.repeat('success and can_test', setup='success, can_test = True, True', number= 100000, repeat=1000))`. This takes the fastest test over 1000 repeats. For me `or` is slightly faster than `and`. See https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/timeit.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was an interesting question, so I decided to deeply investigate your main concern.

```
# required modules line_profiler, matplotlib, seaborn abd scipy
import time as dt 
from line_profiler import LineProfiler
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from scipy import stats

success = True
can_test = True 
def and_op():
    for x in range(2000):
        s = success and can_test
def or_op():
    for x in range(2000):
        s = success or can_test
or_op_list = []
for x in range(0,1000):
    lp = LineProfiler()
    lp_wrapper = lp(or_op)
    lp_wrapper()
    lstats = lp.get_stats()
    total_time = 0
    for v in lstats.timings.values():
        for op in v:
            total_time += op[-1]
            final = op[-1]
        operator = final/total_time
    or_op_list.append(operator)

and_op_list = []
for x in range(0,1000):
    lp = LineProfiler()
    lp_wrapper = lp(and_op)
    lp_wrapper()
    lstats = lp.get_stats()
    total_time = 0
    for v in lstats.timings.values():
        for op in v:
            total_time += op[-1]
            final = op[-1]
        operator = final/total_time
    and_op_list.append(operator)
sns.kdeplot(and_op_list, label = 'AND')
sns.kdeplot(or_op_list, label = 'OR')
plt.show()
print(stats.ttest_ind(and_op_list,or_op_list, equal_var = False))
```

[image]

pvalue=1.8293386245013954e-103

Indeed the "or" is statistically significant and different as compared to the "and" operation

Comment: BTW, notice that if you try one time each function it may happen that the "or" is slower than the "and" due to random fluctuation.

Answer (score 0):

When I run your code on my machine, it prints, sometimes, that `True and True` are faster than `True or True`, too.

The ***reason*** for this phenomenon is that `dt.time()` in your code measures time in ***a scale of "microsecond"*** (i.e. 1000 nanoseconds), but, this ***microsecond-scale is too sparse to measure time taken for every execution*** of `if success and can_test:` or `if success or can_test:`. In most cases, the time taken by `if success and can_test:` or `if success or can_test:` is ***less than 1 microsecond***.

So in the parts of your code below:

> ```py
> for i in range(10000000):
>    start = dt.time()
>        if success and can_test:  # a dust particle
>        stop = dt.time()
>        time += stop - start  # measured by a normal scale ruler
> ```

> ```py
> for i in range(10000000):
>    start = dt.time()
>        if success or can_test:  # a dust particle
>        stop = dt.time()
>        time += stop - start  # measured by a normal scale ruler
> ```

What your code is doing is like ***measuring every dust particle by a normal scale ruler*** and ***adding the measured values***. Since ***the measurement errors are huge***, the result is ***distorted***.

To investigate further, if we execute the code below (`d` records the time taken with its frequency):

```py
import time as dt
from pprint import pprint

success = True
can_test = True

time = 0
d = {}
for i in range(10000000):
    start = dt.time_ns()
    if success and can_test:  # a dust particle
        stop = dt.time_ns()
        diff_time = stop - start  # measurement by a normal scale ruler
        d[diff_time] = d.get(diff_time, 0) + 1
        time += diff_time
print(f'"and" operation took: {time} ns')
print('"and" operation time distribution:')
pprint(d)
print()

time = 0
d = {}
for i in range(10000000):
    start = dt.time_ns()
    if success or can_test:  # a dust particle
        stop = dt.time_ns()
        diff_time = stop - start  # measurement by a normal scale ruler
        d[diff_time] = d.get(diff_time, 0) + 1
        time += diff_time
print(f'"or" operation took: {time} ns')
print('"or" operation time distribution:')
pprint(d)
```

It will print like the following:

```
"and" operation took: 1467442000 ns
"and" operation time distribution:
{0: 8565832,
 1000: 1432066,
 2000: 136,
 3000: 24,
 4000: 12,
 5000: 15,
 6000: 10,
 7000: 12,
 8000: 6,
 9000: 7,
 10000: 6,
 11000: 3,
 12000: 191,
 13000: 722,
 14000: 170,
 15000: 462,
 16000: 23,
 17000: 30,
 18000: 27,
 19000: 10,
 20000: 12,
 21000: 11,
 22000: 61,
 23000: 65,
 24000: 9,
 25000: 2,
 26000: 2,
 27000: 3,
 28000: 1,
 29000: 4,
 30000: 4,
 31000: 2,
 32000: 2,
 33000: 2,
 34000: 3,
 35000: 3,
 36000: 5,
 37000: 4,
 40000: 2,
 41000: 1,
 42000: 2,
 43000: 2,
 44000: 2,
 48000: 2,
 50000: 3,
 51000: 3,
 52000: 1,
 53000: 3,
 54000: 1,
 55000: 4,
 58000: 1,
 59000: 2,
 61000: 1,
 62000: 4,
 63000: 1,
 84000: 1,
 98000: 1,
 1035000: 1,
 1043000: 1,
 1608000: 1,
 1642000: 1}

"or" operation took: 1455555000 ns
"or" operation time distribution:
{0: 8569860,
 1000: 1428228,
 2000: 131,
 3000: 31,
 4000: 22,
 5000: 8,
 6000: 8,
 7000: 6,
 8000: 3,
 9000: 6,
 10000: 3,
 11000: 4,
 12000: 173,
 13000: 623,
 14000: 174,
 15000: 446,
 16000: 28,
 17000: 22,
 18000: 31,
 19000: 9,
 20000: 11,
 21000: 8,
 22000: 42,
 23000: 72,
 24000: 7,
 25000: 3,
 26000: 1,
 27000: 5,
 28000: 2,
 29000: 2,
 31000: 1,
 33000: 1,
 34000: 2,
 35000: 4,
 36000: 1,
 37000: 1,
 38000: 2,
 41000: 1,
 44000: 1,
 45000: 2,
 46000: 2,
 47000: 2,
 48000: 2,
 49000: 1,
 50000: 1,
 51000: 2,
 53000: 1,
 61000: 1,
 64000: 1,
 65000: 1,
 942000: 1}
```

And we can see that about 85.7% of trying to measure time (`8565832 / 10000000` equals `0.8565832` and `8569860 / 10000000` equals `0.8569860`) failed since it just measured `0` nanoseconds. And about 14.3% of trying to measure time (`1432066 / 10000000` equals `0.1432066` and `1428228/10000000` equals `0.1428228`) measured `1000` nanoseconds. And, needless to say, the rest (less than 0.1%) of trying to measure time also resulted in a sale of `1000` nanoseconds. We can see that ***microsecond-scale is too sparse to measure time taken for each execution***.

---

But we can still use the ***normal scale ruler***. By ***getting together the dust particles*** and use the ruler to ***measure the dustball***. So we can try the following code instead:

```py
import time as dt

success = True
can_test = True

start = dt.time()
for i in range(10000000):  # getting together the dust particles
    if success and can_test:  # a dust particle
        pass
stop = dt.time()
time = stop - start  # measure the size of the dustball
print(f'"and" operation took: {time} seconds')

start = dt.time()
for i in range(10000000):  # getting together the dust particles
    if success or can_test:  # a dust particle
        pass
stop = dt.time()
time = stop - start  # measure the size of the dustball
print(f'"or" operation took: {time} seconds')
```

It will print like the following:

```
"and" operation took: 0.6261420249938965 seconds
"or" operation took: 0.48876094818115234 seconds
```

---

Or, we can use a ***fine-scale ruler*** [`dt.perf_counter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.perf_counter) which can ***measure the size of every dust particle exactly***, like the following:

```py
import time as dt

success = True
can_test = True

time = 0
for i in range(10000000):
    start = dt.perf_counter()
    if success and can_test:  # a dust particle
        stop = dt.perf_counter()
        time += stop - start  # measured by a fine-scale ruler
print(f'"and" operation took: {time} seconds')

time = 0
for i in range(10000000):
    start = dt.perf_counter()
    if success or can_test:  # a dust particle
        stop = dt.perf_counter()
        time += stop - start  # measured by a fine-scale ruler
print(f'"or" operation took: {time} seconds')
```

It will print like the following:

```
"and" operation took: 1.6929048989996773 seconds
"or" operation took: 1.3965214280016083 seconds
```

---

Surely, `True or True` is faster than `True and True`!